# Decomposition over finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, finite-fields

Let $r$ is prime, $s = r^m$ and $\tau \in \mathbb{F}_s$. How to prove, that if polynomial $x^r - x - \tau \in \mathbb{F}_s[x]$ has a root, hence it decomposes on linear factors.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *Artin-Schreier* equation. If $\alpha$ is a root, then
$\alpha+\beta$ is a root for all $\beta\in\Bbb F_r$. So the polynomial
has $r$ distinct roots.